# Java 1.5 compatible pattern that will handle all possible exceptions without exception swallowed/lost and resources closing?

Tags: java, exception

I have some method that uses some resources that should be closed at the end and the method itself and resource closing could throw everything including IO Connection and so on exceptions, some Runtime exceptions and even Errors (everything what inherits Throwable OOM is often case.).I want to handle all Exceptions without losing information and to send/throw the most important exception to the client (supposingly the runtime exceptions/errors?) This is the pattern I use (it's java 1.5 so I can't use resource features from 1.7):

```
Throwable thr=null;
try {
    methodThatCouldThrowCheckedExceptionAndErrorAndRuntimeExcpetion();
    log("method succesfully executed.");
} catch (IKnowThisException ikte) {
    //Exception will be not lost
    log("Method was not executed ,and I can suggest further actions",itke);
    thr=ikte;
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // This exception will be not lost too     
    log("Method was not executed ,and I don't know why.",t);
    thr=t;
} finally {
    try{
            // The method below - of course contains the standard null checkers.   
        closeResourcesMethodThatCouldThrowEverythingToo();
        log("resources were closed.");
    } catch (IKnowThisEscpetionToo iktet) {
        log(iktet);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Resources were not closed , because of the known exception and I can suggest some actions" , ijtet);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        log(t);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Resources were not closed and I don't know why" , t);
    }
    // in case resources are closed we can re-throw exception from try{} block
    if ( thr != null ) {
        throw thr;
    }   
}
```

But I'm not completely sure it's the best approach [.Here a similar approach i sused](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/exception-handling-templates.html) . But it does not handle unchecked exceptions (do I need to handle them?) Is there a case when I can lost valuable information? In the most examples I found nothing special is done about Errors/RuntimeExcpetions , but I want them logged. Is there a better approach? May be I should construct a more complicated chained exception to keep information compacted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at how the compiler rewrites the try-with-resources pattern in Java 1.7.  Below is a simple example of the pattern in source level 1.7, followed by a decompiled version with try-with-resources sugaring disabled:

```
// Original:
public void test() throws IOException {
    try (final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()) {
        writer.write("This is only a test.");
    }
}

// Decompiled:
public void test() throws IOException {
    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Throwable t = null;
    try {
        writer.write("This is only a test.");
    }
    catch (Throwable t2) {
        t = t2;
        throw t2;
    }
    finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            if (t != null) {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                }
                catch (Throwable t2) {
                    t.addSuppressed(t2);
                }
            }
            else {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly, the `addSuppressed()` method was only introduced in Java 1.7, but you could create a custom exception class that introduces this behavior, as @erickson suggests in his answer.  If only one exception occurs, simply rethrow that one.  Otherwise, replace it with the custom exception, wrap the original as the cause, and add any suppressed exceptions that occurred during closing of resources.

Comment: Very clever idea  to look at decompiled 1.7 code :-) .Probably will accept this an answer (and the fact that it's close to the my way makes me glad :-D )

Answer (score 2):

To preserve all of the errors, it would be best to use a custom exception class, that provides something like ARM's "suppressed exception" collection.

If the method throws an exception, this is the (cause of the) main exception. If closing resources raises additional exceptions, they are added to the main as suppressed exceptions.

If the method completes without failure, but closing resources raises an exception, the first becomes the main exception, and subsequent resource close failures are added to it as suppressed exceptions.

If a resource was intended to have side effects like writing a file or updating a database, the application needs to determine what to do when closing that resource fails. Using a general purpose mechanism that hides those resource closure exceptions would not allow the application to make that determination, and would only be useful in the rare cases where the application doesn't care if any output is actually produced.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, un-checked exception should not be handle. But you can handle by catching broader exception such as "Exception" before finally block.

Comment: That's what my class does.

Comment: what if both `finally` and `try` blocks throw an unchecked exception? One of them will be lost without handling.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read my blog post [Clean Up After Yourself](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html) (Grab my Close class) and then

```
import static com.frischcode.util.Close.close;

// Where ... is any number of things to close (in finally block - naturally).
close(...);
```

Comment: Why all exceptions are ignored and not logged/printed - not even simple print stack trace? Why is there `final` in `catch (final IOException ignored)` (first time I see such thing - sorry for the stupid question). How `RuntimeExceptions/Errors` are handles - I want them logged too...What bothers me most is the case when both in used method and closing resources there's unchecked exception..

Comment: You should not try and handle unrecoverable Exceptions. Because I didn't want exceptions logged on close (why would I care, I made a good faith effort to close it).

Comment: If there's not closed FileStream in a further moment it could become not possible to delete file or If there's not closed connection it could become not possible to create another one.It could be not recovarable state but ,it's something important that the client should know.The main goal here is to not lost important information about the state of the resources I use and infomation to be logged in best possible way.

Comment: My class is under Creative Commons and allows commercial use. Feel free to modify it, you can send me a patch if you want - I might even accept it.